# Bitlocker Will Not Encrypt on Fixed-Data Drive

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, bitlocker

I have recently encrypted my system (C:) drive, using Bitlocker, on my W7 Enterprise box. This machine is not associated with a domain. I would like to encrypt my remaining fixed data drives, as well. Unfortunately, when I attempt to do so I receive the following error: **The specified domain does not exist or could not be contacted.**

I first thought it is trying to send recovery keys to a domain controller that is not there. I have disabled, enabled, and not configured all relevant AD bitlocker options found within Local Computer Policy>Admin Templates>Win Components>Bitlocker. I have forced gpupdate and restarted, after every modification. None of this has resolved the error.

I would appreciate any help to resolve this annoying issue.